# Back-up battery

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging, protection, backup

for a project I would like to design a system which would allow me to feed my application's logic rail from a back-up battery if the main battery would somehow stop functionioning (most likely due to depletion or some other exotic case). 
The battery should should stay charged and opperational and only be used in an event of main battery failure/discharge to backup or send all data processed by the CPU. Also, this system should keep the battery disconnected when the device is turned off so the logic won't start working even when turned off. Please consider my block-diagram below.
Does such a thing exist, if yes, what's it called, if no, why do people not use it?
Regards[image]

Comment: What you have described sounds almost exactly like any electronic gadget (mobile phone, laptop computer) that charges from an external power supply.  Just treat "MainBatt" as the external power supply.

Comment: Is switching time important? If so consider a ups...

Comment: @SolarMike it's important in the sense that I absolutely cannot lose any data stored in the RAM. The capacitor-bank on the SMPS is quite large, so if it's reasonable, I do not forsee any problems here. Do such small scale UPS exist? Had no idea, I will do my research, thanks.

Comment: @SimonB well, not really, it's an agv with a data processing unit. And in the event of a failure (discharged battery, damaged battery lead, idk,..) it should have a bit of back-up juice to upload, or at least store the processed data.

Comment: Then you need to look at the logic of the ups...

Comment: Try googling power path controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's called buck-boost battery charger ( if reversible ) 
Renesas has a portfolio with this family, ISL9241.